# How to create an Eclipse project for an OPC DA interface?

Tags: java, eclipse, opc, scada

I am a consulter and started shortly in a project where we have to use both the OPC DA & the REST API. But in a first step, we decided to install Eclipse SCADA & make a communication with an OPC DA simulator. The first job is to install an Eclipse SCADA project, because SCADA includes both interfaces with pure Java & does not need any OS-specific code/resources like DLLs etc.

On the Web, I found a [tutorial](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseSCADA/Tutorials/EclipseMagazin), but the page seems to be outdated. The enlisted resources such as this does not exist (anymore). The message reads:

```
No software site found at http://git.eclipse.org/c/eclipsescada/org.eclipse.scada.base.git.
Do you wish to edit the location [ No ] [ Yes ]
```

What I need is a simple tutorial that creates an appropriate Eclipse project & communicates with an OPC DA simulator.

**What we have done sofar:**

- Installed the Oracle VM VirtualBox Linux Debian to run near to Raspberry Pi
- Installed the Oracle VM VirtualBox Windows 7 to run the
- Installed a Windows 7 virtual machine to run the Matrikon OPC Simultor
- Installed Eclipse Kepler 4.3, a it is said that Eclipse SCADA is running there
- The Java 1.8 SE & its JDK

Do you know resources for an OPC DA newbie?

Thank you in advance!